# AnnotationConfigApplicationContext parameters

Tags: spring

When I create the context:

```
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringApp.class);
```

where *SpringApp* is not annotated neither with *@Configuration* nor with anything else.
I'm getting the *springApp* bean anyway.
Why? The documentation says

> Create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, deriving bean
>   definitions from the given **annotated classes** and automatically
>   refreshing the context.

So I can't understand why *springApp* bean is created if there are no annotations there.

Comment: Really, we can find this phrase online.
But what do '"JSR-330" compliant' classes mean? Classes with a zero constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is legit. Spring does not handle the `SpringApp.class` as a Configuration **but** respects it's deriving bean-definitions. The Spring-App-Instnce is of scope singleton.

From the documentation:

> (red:the Constructor) Create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, deriving bean definitions from the given annotated classes and automatically refreshing the context.